# Is it possible to use Android 4 features on older versions?

Tags: android, api, version, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, grid-layout

Since Android 4 has some nice new APIs, and since Android is Open Source, I've thought,
Why not, for the time being, use the new APIs as if they are a part of the application, and when the time is right (when most users use the new version), use the official APIs instead?

For example, I think that the [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html), and maybe other new stuff, could be imported into projects.

My question is: Has anyone done such a thing? and if so, How well does it perform?
Also, if anyone has done it, please publish a project, so that everyone could enjoy it.

I also wonder why Google doesn't provide such a mechanism in order to give more power to old versions and also to get rid of deprecated things.

---

google does have some support for features of newer versions.
for gridlayout , it's possible to use something like on this example:
http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/checkout

for actionbar and fragments , there is the support library and there is the [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which is based on it (not created by google, but very good and even better ).

Comment: Indeed there are several libraries that try to backport features available only on newer versions to older Android phones. I'm not sure about `GridLayout` (since I never used them), but I wouldn't be surprised if someone else already wrote it. The question is a bit too broad because in the end it will depend on what you're looking for exactly. Because people port some things and not others, of course... there is no universal backport-switch.

Comment: about gridLayout , they added a jar library for API7+ , on the folder "...\support\v7\gridlayout" . however, they didn't include any sample , so i tried using it myself . it never worked . has anyone else succeeded using it?

Comment: ok , this example worked:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/GridLayout0.html
but this example didn't:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few backports of new features to older devices available. The most prominent one are probably the Fragments from Honeycomb. Also this "slide to change tab" (ViwewPager) feature of e.g. Google+ app is available in such a compatibility library.

See e.g. the [v13 lib](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/package-summary.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Comment: you probably mean v4 , since v13 works only on API 13 and above ...
anyway, what about the other features on ICS that don't exist on older versions? this is what is interesting to me .

Comment: currently android has support libraries , including something for gridLayout . so i guess this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I also wonder why google doesn't provide such a mechanism in order to give more power to old versions

[They do](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Also, though it is technically possible to extract one component from one of the newer APIs and implement it at the application level in one of the older versions. I think you'll find that it is harder than it may seem. Using the compatibility library that they provide is probably your best bet.

> when most users use the new version

The vast majority of devices that have made contact with the market in the last 2 weeks are on versions 7 - 10

[see here for a breakdown of what versions are in use.](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Comment: are you sure that , for example , the GridLayout could be used on any android version device ( after importing this library, of course)?

Comment: I am not, I've never used it. I just know that is all they provide as backborts, anything else you'd have to manually copy to your project yourself.

Comment: ok , i've tested it , and it doesn't work. it gives an exception :

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class GridLayout